# How to apply two conditions to a split?

Tags: perl, split

I want to split on the letter "b" without removing it from the output. I only want to split on the "b" if it is not followed by a "c". How can I combine these two conditions? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$val ="abbcdebffgbhiabbbcde";
@as = split(/(?<=b)/,"$val",) if !~/(bc)/g; 
foreach (@as){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

This is my expected output:

```
ab
bcdeb #here 'b' present but not split because succeeding 'c' is present.
ffgb
hiab
b
bcde #here 'b' present but not split because succeeding 'c' is present.
```

At the moment, my code splits on all the "b"s. How can I change it to combine the two conditions?

Comment: I notice that you have not accepted any answers to any of your questions. Don't forget to upvote answers that you find useful and accept your favourite answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you @Tom Fenech. I understood. further i'll vote for accepted answers.

Comment: No problem. As well as voting, you should click on the ✔ next to your favourite answer. This will mark it as accepted. You should do this on all your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You want a *negative lookahead assertion*:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $val = "abbcdebffgbhiabbbcde";
my @as = split(/(?<=b)(?!c)/, $val);

print "$_\n" foreach @as;
```

This splits on any point preceded by the letter "b", as long as it is not followed by a "c". The `(?!c)` is a negative lookahead assertion, which means that any "b" followed by a "c" will not match.

Output:

```
ab
bcdeb
ffgb
hiab
b
bcde
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a slight variation of my previous answer to your question:

```
$data = "abbcdebffgbhiabbbcde";

while ($data =~ /b[^c]/g) {
    print substr($data, 0, $+[0]-1, "") . "\n";
}
print $data,"\n";
```

#### Output:

```
ab
bcdeb
ffgb
hiab
b
bcde
```